# How will catch data that your computer/android sends to the internet?

Tags: android, bash, network-programming

I recently learned from my cmpsc class how data is sent through out the internet. But I was wonder if there was a way to monitor data segments or packets being sent from my computer and modify the data manually through a bash script or something. If there is a why for a computer to do shouldn't there also be a similar way for a android to monitor the packets being sent out. To sum it up how will i monitor information that my computer and android send to the internet when I am using apps and other programs?

Comment: Do you have root?  Are you on cellular internet or wifi?  These things change the answers.

Comment: I do have root and what will be the difference between a cellular internet or a wifi?

Comment: On wifi the easiest way to track all data is to do so at the router.  You can't do that for cellular.